Comparing model probability estimates between groups (teams)
This is probably a very simply question but I don't have a deep statistical background and want to make sure I am applying the appropriate analysis to this data. I have an expected goals (xG) model (from logistic regression done in R) and want to compare the shot values (probability of scoring) that are predicted by the model to test whether there is any difference in the 'quality' of shots taken between teams in a recent tournament. Because the data are probabilities derived from model output I am unsure of the most appropriate way of making this comparison. If this were actual scoring rate I would have both the total number of shots and the number scored and be able to do something on the proportion scored. But here I just have the model generated probabilities for each shot for each team. The frequency distributions are right skewed so is it as simple as using a non-parametric test like Kruskal-Wallis for example?
